# Displaying BOTH the key value in a f.select

Tags: ruby

Hopefully the last question I'll ask on SO for a minute, sorry if you guys are getting sick of me!

I have a hash of shipping_option keys and price values.  I want a user to be able to choose their option on a select form.  My problem now is I can't get the key and the value to display at the same time in the form.  I thought I could do:

```
      <%= f.select :shipping_type, ship_hash.map {|k, v| [k, v]}%>
```

but only the key populates in the form...

[image]

How can I also get the price?

**Update**

```
<%= options_for_select(ship_hash.map { |k, v| ["#{k}: #{v}", k] }) %>
```

displays both of the key and value but only saves the key into the DB, how can I also save the corresponding value WITH the key into the DB? Or Save the Value into it's own, separate column in the DB?

```
  <%= f.select :shipping_type, options_for_select(ship_hash.map { |k, v| ["#{k}: #{v}", "#{k}  " + "#{v}"] }) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output your hash in a select box, read about the [select tag](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease) and [options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select). In your case, you want to change your `ship_hash` to something that looks like this:

```
[
  ["FedEx Ground Home Delivery: $9.78", "FedEx Ground Home Delivery"], 
  ["FedEx 2 Day: $20.59", "FedEx 2 Day"], 
  ["FedEx Standard Overnight: $33.78", "FedEx Standard Overnight"], 
  ["USPS Priority Mail 1-Day: $5.60", "USPS Priority Mail 1-Day"]
]
```

To do that, you can use the `map` method like this:

```
ship_hash.map { |k, v| ["#{k}: #{v}", k] }
```

Using that as the argument of `options_for_select` like this:

```
<%= options_for_select(ship_hash.map { |k, v| ["#{k}: #{v}", k] }) %>
```

will then yield the following output:

```
<option value="FedEx Ground Home Delivery">
  FedEx Ground Home Delivery: $9.78
</option>
<option value="FedEx 2 Day">
  FedEx 2 Day: $20.59
</option>
<option value="FedEx Standard Overnight">
  FedEx Standard Overnight: $33.78
</option>
<option value="USPS Priority Mail 1-Day">
  USPS Priority Mail 1-Day: $5.60
</option>
```

which should be what you wanted.